# addition theorem for product of THREE Bessel functions: $\sum_n I_{n+m}(a) I_{n-m}(b) I_{p-n}(c)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, special-functions, bessel-functions, hypergeometric-function

Working on a problem of lattice Green functions (LGF) I encountered a summation shown in the title question:
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty  I_{n+m}(a) I_{n-m}(b) I_{p-n}(c) .
$$
 It is part of wider summation: 
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty  I_{n+m}(a) I_{n-m}(b) I_{p-n}(c) I_{q+m}(c)
$$
where all the indices n, m, p, q are integers. 
The above formula is part of still wider integrals:
$$
\int_0^\infty dt \exp(-E t)\sum_n \sum_m  I_{n+m}(a t) I_{n-m}(b t) I_{p-n}(c t) I_{q+m}(c t)
$$
or
$$
\int_0^\infty dt \exp(-E t) I_w(f t) \sum_n \sum_m   I_{n+m}(a t) I_{n-m}(b t) I_{p-n}(c t) I_{q+m}(c t)
$$
the former is LGF in 2 dimensions (2d) the latter - in 3d.

Does any one know, how to simplify any of these formulas getting rid of summations? Or how (IF) it could be done? There is Neumann/Graf addition formula which does that for the product of TWO Bessel functions but has any of you seen an analogue for three? How to intersperse the third index into summation? Any simplified versions for $a=b$ or $p=0$ or $q=0$ or $p=0=q$ or with $J_n$ instead of $I_n$ would be also of use. I tried various formulas from Gradshtein-Ryzhik and Abramovitz-Stegun but to no avail. Any hint how to attack the problem?

Comment: Those two summations seem incredibly difficult (too difficult for me),  but the integral you mention may be doable without needing some Bessel function addition theorem. Are you interested in an evaluation of the integral that doesn't require doing the sums first? Or is your main question here specifically about the sums?

Comment: Both things are interesting in fact. Performing integrals would yield closed forms for LGF on rectangular (2d) or tetragonal lattice (3d) with next-nearest neighbor hopping (c<>0). The one in 2d is known (given by elliptic integral). Obtaining it in 3d - with one Bessel function in the integrand more - would be a remarkable achievement, given that obtaining it even in nearest-neighbor hopping case (c=0) was difficult like hell (yielding a product of two elliptic integrals).

Comment: On the other hand, performing the summations only would be sufficient to check a very useful theorem, which I proved in nn case: that the lattice average of $G(p,q,n)*G(p1,q1,n1)=-G'(p1-p,q1-q,n1-n)$, where G is LGF and args are site indices.